# Waiting for the result of async method using Task<T>.Result()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mstest

I've a method in my controller with this signature

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
```

This is what I'm doing in my unit test to wait for the result of *Index()*

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestIndex()
{
   var controller = new MyController();
   var result = controller.Index().Result;

   // Asserts here
}
```

But the documentation say that the way to test *async* methods is using *async Task* in the signature of the test method and using *await* like this

```
public async Task TestIndex()
{
   var controller = new MyController();
   var result = await controller.Index();

   // Asserts here
}
```

I really want to know what is the difference between the way the documentation say and the way I'm doing it?

What's wrong doing the test the way I'm doing it?

PS: Even the exceptions thrown in the *Index* method are shown in the *Test Explorer* window.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing it the way the documentation says to? When you're using `async` methods your code should be `async` "top-down" and calling `.Result` in a blocking manner must be avoided.

Comment: When async method is void your test must be avoided as you cant wait till the result. I'm not sure why you can't do this here though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx discusses unit testing async.